# C pointer content assignment from other pointer

Tags: pointers

While I was trying to solve problem from of Dennis Ritchie. I got following error. But I have no idea, why this is happening. Seems like it should work. 
I am using MacOS Mojave and standard gcc compiler. 
My source code is following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// copies most n characters of t to s; 
char *sstrcnpy(char *s, char *t, int n)
{
    // *pointer - content of the pointer will be assigned 
    char *ret; // ret stores the content of the dst 
    while(n--){
        *ret++ = *t++; 
    }
    printf("%s\n", ret);  
    return ret; 
}
int main()
{
    char *s = "Destination"; 
    char *t = "sour"; 
    char *sstrcnpy(char *s, char *t, int n); 
    sstrcnpy(s,t,3);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0; 
}
```

Then when I try to run this code. The terminal gave me following error.

```
nasantogtokhs-MacBook-Pro:C nasaa$ ./5_5
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Or instead of the Segmentation error, some of other source codes it was

```
bus error: 10
```

Then I have tried to dig down by using **lldb** of Mac. Then I got following error.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000ef7 5_5`sstrcnpy(s="Destination", t="our", n=2) at exercise_5_5.c:10
   7        // *pointer - content of the pointer will be assigned 
   8        char *ret; // ret stores the content of the dst 
   9        while(n--){
-> 10           *ret++ = *t++; 
   11       }
   12       printf("%s\n", ret);  
   13       return ret;
```

I think this is related to memory access. It seems like somehow my computer does not allow to assign value into the pointer content on the separate function. But I have seen other examples. It seems like it supposed to work just fine.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Clearly, when I initialized the pointer of char, it cannot be changed, but we can change the content if we allocate memory for it. 
I think the reason of that error is, when I initialize it with explicitly assigning to array of char, the program was trying to access unaccepted block of memory and tries to change it, which is correct because the initialization is just mapping of address of constant in the memory to the pointer. And when with dynamic memory allocation there is no constant in the beginning in the memory allocated for pointer and strcpy function was copying the chars fine.